# HTML Collapsible with text instead of image?

Tags: html

How can I make an expandable text using only HTML?

I have this working code that I had adapted from a tutorial, but I can't find the original tutorial to go backwards. Right now, the image is clicked and text expands below it. The tutorial originally had text, and I changed it to an image, but now I want text for a different project and can't figure it out for the life of me. (Links, etc. have been changed for stackoverflow)

```html
<table style="width:100%"><tr><td>

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/PYIzMc6.jpg" width="200" title="Click to show/hide text" onclick="if(document.getElementById('sizes') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('sizes') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('sizes') .style.display='none'}"/></td></tr><tr>
<td>
<div id="sizes" style="display:none">
<a href="https://facebook.com/">one</a><br/>
<a href="https://tumblr.com/">two</a><br/>
<a href="https://google.com/">three</a><br/></div></td></tr>

</div></td>

</tr></table>
```

I can't figure out how to get the part that is clicked to expand the links to text instead of an image - or both if possible.

Comment: The `onclick` event needs to be in the tag that contains your text. So instead of `<img ... onClick="...">` you'll have for example `<span ... onClick="...">Your text</span>`

Answer (score 0):

You write "using only HTML" but are using inline JavaScript, so I assumed that a JS solution analogous to your example is fine.

Just change your `<img>` tag to a `<span>` (or a `<p>` paragraph, or whatever suits your needs` and remove the image-specific attributes.

Also, your markup had a few unnecessary tags bevore the closing `</table>` tag.

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span
        title="Click to show/hide text"
        onclick="if(document.getElementById('sizes') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('sizes') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('sizes') .style.display='none'}">
          toggle list
        </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="sizes" style="display:none">
        <a href="https://facebook.com/">one</a><br/>
        <a href="https://tumblr.com/">two</a><br/>
        <a href="https://google.com/">three</a><br/></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That works here, but something about the Tumblr editor doesn't like it. I tried with `<p>` instead of `<span>`, as well